# How to add SSL Binding in IIS 7.5

Tags: web-server, ssl, iis-7.5

I had the Default Web Site running on localhost port 80 smoothly. I wanted to enable SSL on it so I first created a Self Signed Certificate in Server Certificates section of IIS Management Console.

Then I clicked on Edit Bindings option on the Default Web Site and Added https binding that uses my newly created certificate.

After that if I try to start the Web Site I get the following error:

"The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process."

What do I need to do to make it work? If I remove the ssl binding it starts working fine.
I'm guessing it can't access the certificate file. What should I do to fix this?

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting the server in HTTP only mode and have a look at the result of the following command:

```
netstat -an | find ":443" | find "LISTENING"
```

If that command doesn't return an empty list, it means you have already something bound to 0.0.0.0:443 You can then use the `netstat -anb` command to find out which process is using that resource. What to do afterward depends on what process you find.

Comment: Skype was eating up 443 port so IIS couldn't listen on it.